# Change column values in pandas based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with source, sellers and default sellers. I need to change the source column based on the conditions below

```
| source  | default seller | seller      |
| --------| -------------- | ------------|
| Amazon  | amazon.com     | na          |
| Amazon  | seller1        | na          |
| Amazon  | seller2        | na          |
| Walmart | na             | walmart.com |
| Walmart | na             | firstcopy   |
| Amazon  | amazon         | na          |
| ebay    | na             | na          |
```

Condition 1

if source is Amazon and default seller value is not in `['amazon','amazon.com','amazon global store uk','amazon warehouse']` , then `df['source'] = Amazon Market place`

if source is Walmart and seller value is not in `['walmart.com']`, then `df['source'] = Wamlart Maketplace`

else don't change anything
I have tried below code

```
for index , row in final_df.iterrows():
    if row['source'] == 'Amazon':
        if row.get('default_seller','').lower() not in amazon_seller_list:
            final_df.at[index, 'source'] = 'Amazon Marketplace'
    elif row['source'] == 'Walmart':
        if row.get('seller','').lower() not in walmart_seller_list:
            final_df.at[index, 'source'] = 'Walmart Marketplace'
    else:
        continue
```

but I am getting Walmart Marketplace as source in all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_a = ['amazon','amazon.com','amazon global store uk','amazon warehouse']
list_b = ['walmart.com']

df[source] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Amazon Market Place' if (x[source] == 'Amazon' and x['default seller'] not in list_a) else x['source'], axis = 1)

df[source] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Walmart Market Place' if (x[source] == 'Walmart' and x['default seller'] not in list_b) else x['source'], axis = 1)
```